# Get source code of element in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, froala

I have a container which has dynamic content in it. The content can be edited by users with an inline editor called [Froala Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor).

```
<div id="froala-editor">
    DYNAMIC HTML CONTENT 
</div>
```

I want to output the source code generated by the froala editor into a php variable.

I have tried using froala editor's function for it, but it does not get any result.

```
$('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('html.get');
```

I also tried to write my own function:

```
<?php 
    ob_start(); 
?>
<script>
    document.write($('div#froala-editord').html());
</script>
<?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $html_output = htmlentities($output);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $html_output;
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

But this snippet gives the result:

```
<script>
    document.write($('div#froala-editor').html());
</script>
```

What I want is to get the source code of the `#froala-editor` div and store it in a php variable.

I also tried to use `file_get_contents()` but the file that has this div also has dynamic content in it.
Also tried the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but it gives back an error using `file_get_contents()`

When the user finished editing the content with the editor, I want to submit a form with a hidden element that has the value of the edited content's source code.

Comment: The php has already finished processing on the server by the time you get the html / javascript output in the browser. You need to make an ajax call to the server if you want to use that value on the server.

Comment: user interface != server side

Comment: use `cURL` instead of old `file_get_contents()`

Comment: I forgot to add this into the question, but I edit it: when the user finished editing the content, I want to submit a form with the content's source code the user edited.